# Uniform convergence of $n \sin(\frac{x}{n})$ over $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

The sequence of functions 
$$f_n(x)=n \sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$$ is pointwise convergent everywhere in the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$ and converges to the function $f(x)=x$.

This function $f(x)$  is continuous in the given interval but that does not tell us anything about the uniform convergence of the given sequence function in the given interval.

I try to find out the supremum of $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ i.e.$|n \sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)-x|$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$.

Using derivative test for Maxima/minima, I get $\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)=1$. This gives me $\frac{x}{n}=2p\pi$ where $p$ is an integer. Now, $x=2p\pi n$.

We get supremum as $\left|n \sin\left(\frac{2p\pi n}{n}\right)-2p \pi n\right|= 2p\pi n$.

This goes to $\infty$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$. Is this enough to prove that given function sequence is not uniformly convergent in given interval by application of $M_n$ test?

Comment: No test is required. Just use the definition. $\sup_x |f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq 2\pi n$ by your calculation and $2\pi n \to \infty$ so the convergence is not uniform **by definition**.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy What if we use the same methodology to prove or disprove the uniform convergence in a finite interval $[-r,r]$? But the same sequence function is uniform convergent in that interval. Is it because of the fact that $x=2pπn$ won't be contained in a finite interval $[-r,r]$?

Comment: Yes, the sequence is not contained in $[-r,r]$.